# Ajax and jQuery XML parsing problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

Issue: it only appends "undefined" for each element.

I've been reading links for the better part of two hours to try getting past this issue, but have exhausted the resources.  Sorry if this question is asked a lot.

I'm trying to fetch an XML response and make it into something meaningful. So far, I've used data.gov data sets just to test it out.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>jQuery and XML</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="language" content="en" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body

<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "xml",
  url: "https://health.data.ny.gov/api/views/wssx-idhx/rows.xml",
  success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find("row").each(function(){
            $("#output").append($(this).attr("facility_name") + "<br />");          
        });
    }
 });
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

For example, the url I'm testing with gives this as a response:

```
<response>
<row>
  <row _id="48" _uuid="760E4665-B5D8-489A-ACC3-9D649D4F1989" _position="48" _address="http://health.data.ny.gov/resource/wssx-idhx/48">
  <facility_name>Orchard Grove Residences</facility_name>
  <address>2000 Southwestern Drive W. E.</address>
  <county>Chautauqua</county>
  <city>Jamestown</city>
  <zip>14701</zip>
  <.....>
</row>
<response>
```

That is just one of many elements in the XML response.  I feel like there is something simple here that I'm missing, or else something is fundamentally wrong with my thought process.

Comment: A bit off topic, but is there a reason you're using a jQuery version from [february 2010](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases?after=1.4.4rc3) (1.4.2)?

Comment: I've been going through some tutorials.  Must have pasted a really old link to the library because the tutorial was probably written around that time.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to append the text of the `facility_name` child of each `row` in the XML.

Therefore you can't use `attr`. Instead write

```
$("#output").append($(this).find("facility_name").text() + "<br />");
```

Comment: Ah, I knew there was a fundamental misunderstanding on my part somewhere.  Thanks, that makes a whole lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

`facility_name` is not an attribute of `row`, it's a child node.  `$(this).attr("facility_name")` will retrieve something that looks like `<row facility_name=""...>`, which is not what you want.

You need to use `$(this).find("facility_name")` to get the child node.  Since there's only one you could just get the first item in the array instead of doing another `.each`.

Comment: That makes sense to me now.  Thanks!